# Posting data to my controller for API call - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to get my form inputs into my controller so that I can pass them in my API call.

I have this form:

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
    <form ng-submit="storeProject()">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Title</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="projectData.title">
            </label>
            <label class="item">
                <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Create Project</button>
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

I then have this controller:

```
.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $auth, $http, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {

    $scope.projectData = {};

    $scope.storeProject = function(projectData) {

        console.log("add project: ", $scope.projectData);

    };
})
```

And this in my app.js:

```
.state('app.new_project', {
    url: '/projects/new',
    data: {
        permissions: {
            except: ['anonymous'],
            redirectTo: 'app.auth'
        }
    },
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/new_project.html',
            controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

I have my API working great, but just need to be able to get my values from the form to post.

Need to be able to do projectData.title etc.

I always get undefined in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$scope.storeProject = function(projectData) {
```

by

```
$scope.storeProject = function() {
```

Or replace

```
ng-submit="storeProject()"
```

by

```
ng-submit="storeProject(projectData)"
```

That said, I don't see how your posted code could log undefined. My guess is that your actual code is

```
console.log("add project: ", projectData);
```

Comment: One of those occasions where I was certain I tried every combination, but somehow your simple solution worked. Thanks :)